# SSRS Report Authentication

Tags: sql-server, authentication, reporting-services

I am a consultant that is fairly new to SSRS. I have developed a couple of reports at my current client and the reports have been deployed so they are accessible using the ReportManager. Initially, I was the only user of these reports.

Reporting services is deployed to the same server that is housing the databases (SQL Server 2012).

The credentials (SQL credentials) for the data sources of the reports are currently my own user credentials.

Then my scope changed and all the employees should be able to view the reports. After speaking to the DBA of the server, we decided to create a centralized set of credentials for everyone to use (1 username, 1 password). I was informed that because of the way SSRS is installed, these centralized credentials had to either be a domain user (which needed to be added as a user on the server) or a local user on the server. The local user was created.

The problem then became that this is a huge security risk for the company and they want individual user credentials for each user in the company (roughly 3000 employees).

The server where SSRS is deployed is a production server so adding all the users as accounts on the server is not an option.

Is there any way to allow these users to access the reports?

I have a list of the credentials if that helps in any way. I did Google the problem and saw authentication methods such as 'Custom Authentication' or 'Form Authentication' but I couldn't find proper examples and the support pages of Microsoft did help me much (unless I haven't found the right page yet).

There is a secondary domain which all the employees uses, but again they do not want to allocate user access to the server (logon to the server) to the employees.

Comment: If you're using AD, why not add a group that the staff member accounts are part of to the users that can access the SSRS reports in the Report Manager/Browser?

Comment: Will the AD need to be enabled on the server itself and give the users access to the server? The company has 2 AD systems: one for the server ranges and access (not everyone has accounts on this domain) and then an AD that is used for 'proxy' credentials (according to me all the users do have credentials on this AD). The 'proxy' AD will ideally be the one to use.

Comment: Is there trust between the 2 domains? If there is you can still add groups from the other.

Comment: I spoke to the DBA and he doesn't think there is trust between the domains. He will however verify for me. Is there possibly another option to this?

Comment: The client verified, no trust between domains

Comment: Then your only options are to have SSRS open to all, or use custom authentication.

Comment: @Larnu, will custom authenticTion work with my scenario?

Comment: Yes, as custom authentication is exactly that, custom. You design it to your needs.

Comment: @Larnu, thanks. Is there a guide I can follow that might be similar to my scenario? I checked on Microsoft's site but it was not as clear and understanding as I would have hoped.

Comment: You'll need to have a Google/Bing/Yahoo/etc search I'm afraid. The implementation is different for **every** version of SQL Server, and obviously you'll need to find one that fits your needs. Asking for a tutorial on SO is off topic I'm afraid, so asking for one here isn't going to get a response you want. It will not be an easy or simple implementation, however, the choices that the company have made only lend itself to difficult solutions, as they appear to have no trust of their users, and between the domains. Honestly, a very bizarre set up.

Comment: @Larnu, thank you for the guidance. I will search till I find something. Yes, it is a bizarre setup, I unfortunately cannot tell them to change their systems hehe